# Getting reference to a typeid() object?

Tags: c++, constants

Hey im coming from a java background, im reading a c++ book and it says that typeid() returns an object of type_info. But if i try to do something like;

```
type_info *x = typeid(somthing);
```

I get the error : no suitable conversion from const type_info to type_info exists.

Can someone tell me how i can get a reference to a type_info object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `typeid` operator returns a  `const type_info&`. Therefore, you need a const reference, not a pointer:

```
const std::type_info &x = typeid(something);
```

Comment: Thanks! ill add this comment to my documentation :)